# Wordpress ACF Repeater Field on Search Page

Tags: wordpress, search, field, advanced-custom-fields, repeater

I use Advanced Custom Fields for some Posts. On the Category Page all Repeater Fields and Field Group Fields are displayed correct. But on the Search Results Page these type of fields are empty. 
For Example my Code for Movie Actors

```
//Actors
$act1 = get_field('schauspieler_1', $post->ID);
$act2 = get_field('schauspieler_2', $post->ID);
$act3 = get_field('schauspieler_3', $post->ID);
$act4 = get_field('schauspieler_4', $post->ID);
$act5 = get_field('schauspieler_5', $post->ID);
$cast = esc_attr($act1['schauspieler_name']).', '.esc_attr($act2['schauspieler_name']).', '.esc_attr($act3['schauspieler_name']).', '.esc_attr($act4['schauspieler_name']).' und '.esc_attr($act5['schauspieler_name']);
```

it is called

```
<p><?php esc_html_e( 'Actors', 'elvistheme' ); ?>:  <span class="text-grey"><?php echo $cast; ?></span></p>
```

on the Category Page it shows:

**Darsteller: Elvis Presley, Mary Tyler Moore, Barbara McNair, Leora Dana und Jane Elliot**

but on the Search Result Page it shows:

**Darsteller: , , , und**

Normal Fields like Text, Date etc. are displayed correct.

Comment: This is quite confusing. In your question, you mentioned Repeater fields but you haven't mentioned where you actually use a Repeater - that would make sense if you wanted a changeable number of actors and repeat that actor's field group.

Comment: Also, you haven't specified which post types the ACF Field Group is used with. If it's used for all posts. maybe the fields are empty for some posts that show up as search results. To further debug this, you could use `$cast = '[post: '.$post->ID.' type: "'.$post->post_type.'"] '. esc_attr($act1['schauspieler_name']).', '.esc_attr($act2['schauspieler_name']).', '.esc_attr($act3['schauspieler_name']).', '.esc_attr($act4['schauspieler_name']).' und '.esc_attr($act5['schauspieler_name']);`to have the post's ID and type show up  before the actor's names.

Comment: Sorry for that. the Field group is used with standard post type. i have 5 field groups for 5 actors with 2 textfields. 
schauspieler_1 = Group, 1. field - schauspieler_name = Actor Name, 2. field - schauspieler_rollenname = Role Name

Comment: update your question with more code from search.php template. need to see where you are calling these get_field functions

Answer (score 1):

It seems your doing the wrong way to display the ACF content.
just place the simple code:

> $act1 = get_field('schauspieler_1',get_the_ID());
>   $act2 =
>   get_field('schauspieler_2', get_the_ID());
>   $act3 =
>   get_field('schauspieler_3', get_the_ID());
>   $act4 =
>   get_field('schauspieler_4', get_the_ID());
>   $act5 =
>   get_field('schauspieler_5', get_the_ID());
>   echo $act1 . $act2. $act3.
>   $act2. $act4. $act5;

This should work fine inside search page as well provided if your search query matches the relevant keywords from the post in which you are fetching this.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for your Help but it doesn't work. The Fields schauspieler_1, schauspieler_2, schauspieler_3, schauspieler_4 and schauspieler_5 are field groups which have the subfield schauspieler_name